# match at least two patterns from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

the basic code to seach a match for one string

```
cat fileA | grep -Fwf include.txt
```

How do can we use a code to match at least two patterns from that include.list

```
file A 
data1 khc001 khc002 vp005
data1 fbc001 cs004 khc001

include.txt
khc001
khc002
```

correct output line 1: `data1 khc001 khc002 vp005`

in the following e.g only 2 patterns are listed, but the list contains much more
this is why `awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/'` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be rather easy to do this with `awk`, counting the number of fields on each line in `fileA` that are equal to the strings in the `include.txt` file:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { p[$1]; next }
     {
         c = 0
         for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i in p) c++
         if ( c >= 2 ) print
     }' include.txt fileA
```

This first reads the `include.txt` file and uses the words as keys in an associative array.  It then reads the second file and for each row, it iterates over the fields and tests each one to see whether it matches any of the keys.

For each match, we increment a counter, and if the counter is equal or grater than two at the end, we print the line.

---

Alternative formulation of the code for people who likes "one-liners":

```
awk 'NR==FNR {p[$1];next} {c=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i in p) c++} c>=2' include.txt fileA
```

Comment: Thank you. Very informative, using a counter is the best approach.

Comment: @EnrikS Never say something is the "best" approach! ;-)

Comment: Noted :-p So far as a newbie, its very informative to get to know how to use the concept of those who ve been in that field for a long time.

Comment: @EnrikS Note, it also will print next line: `data1 khc001 khc001 vp005`, that is, if the one pattern occurs more than one time.

Comment: @Kusalananda The execution speed is just remarkable.

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming the order of patterns are the same way as in inputfile but not mis-order:

```
grep -F " $(tr '\n' ' ' <patterns)" infile
```

Comment: got stuck nearly 3 hours with a similar code earlier. Am i doing something wrong, the output is not correct, gives me all lines containing at least 1 pattern.

Comment: i nailed it at last. So basically as you said, the each line need to be sorted, else it aint gonna work.

Comment: Yes, means if include.txt contains `x\ny\nz` then that will match a line containing `x y z` and not `x z y` or others. if your fileA is not same order of your include.txt then I would **delete** my answer as it doesn't resolve your question.

Comment: It worked just fine. My file is sorted, actually was running a test on a b c 1 2 3 . Thank your time n help. Appreciate it.

Comment: just a note again that not _sort_, I mentioned _order_ means include.txt containing `v\nd\nz\na` (`\n` is the actual newline) will only match lines in fileA with `v d z a`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following grepception:

```
grep -Fwf <(grep -v $(grep -oFwf include.txt fileA | head -1) include.txt) fileA
```

This will remove one of the matching patterns from `include.txt` and ensure there is at least one other match.

Comment: grep is very useful but because of false positive results, i prefer awk when it comes to that kind of task. But love the idea behind, will obviously tweak that code and use it on something else thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {
    a[NR]=$0
    next }
  !b { b=NR }
  {
    c=$0
    for(i=1;i<b;i++)
        if(!sub("\\<"a[i]"\\>","",c))
            next
  }1
' include.txt file\ A
```

---

> Try to remove each word from include.txt in each line.
>
> If a word is not remove not print the line.

Comment: could you please explain the last argument for `c=$0`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want, so keep the entire line in c. In the for loop remove each word from include.txt in c. At the end, c is not the entire line but $0 is. If it's ok print $0 with the 1 (default action = print).

Comment: Thank you, learn something : 1 is used to evaluate, therefore `}1` stands for a default operation to print $0, which stands for the current line.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Fwonf include.txt file_A | 
uniq | 
cut -d: -f1 | 
printf '%dp\n' $(uniq -d) | 
ed -s file_A
```

#### Testing

**The content of files (file_A more complicated for testing):**

```
$ tail -n +1 -- file_A include.txt 
==> file_A <==
data1 khc001 khc002 vp005
data1 fbc001 cs004 khc001
data1 khc001 khc001 vp005
data1 khc002 khc001 vp005

==> include.txt <==
khc001
khc002
```

**Output**

```
data1 khc001 khc002 vp005
data1 khc002 khc001 vp005
```

Comment: In regards to grep, must say that this code is quite remarkable with the speed. Could please explain how `-Fwonf` works. Nothing came up on Google search.

Comment: @EnrikS You are needing look up into the `man grep` for information about the `-Fwonf` options.